# Finding the greatest distance reached above the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

[image: question]

[image: mark scheme answer]

i dont understand why there is an additional 0.441 added to the final distance... i do understand that the distance travelled by A downwards is equal to the distance moved by B upwards but why the 0.441? i solved it until the point where you find s1 an multiply it by 2 but afterwards it makes no sense.. can someone please explain

Comment: You should include the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

At the point when A hits the ground and stops, B is moving upwards with some velocity. Because of its inertia, B cannot just stop at this point - it continues moving upwards. Since the string is now slack, the only force acting on B is gravity, so its motion is now ballistic. The additional $0.441$ metres ($s_2$) is the distance that B travels upwards after A has hit the ground, until B reaches the top of its ballistic trajectory and starts falling downwards again.

Comment: why doesnt B move downwards if gravity was acting on it?

Comment: @wjkrkdfjkn It does eventually - but initially when A hits the ground, B is moving upwards - so it has to continue moving upwards for some distance until it starts to move downwards - just like a ball that is thrown upwards.

Answer (score 0):

In the moment A reaches the ground B has the same speed but in up direction. so it will go up till its kinetic energy is zero.